# How can I make my Unity dash not to display files in my machine?

Tags: 16.04, unity-dash

I am using Ubuntu 16.04 and I want to customize my dash such that it doesn't show content from my folders, such as files and other folders in them. I tried looking for how to do it here but didn't see anything as such a reason for which my question is.

How can I achieve that?

Comment: I just continued messing around, and then took note of the "Filter results"... I have as thus posted an answer below. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by using unity dash in the launcher. When you click on the unity dash icon, you will see a settings option "Filter results" at the top right corner of the launcher's popover. You can make use of the options within to customize your unity dash for each of the six tabs (found at the bottom of the popover).

I have attached an image below so as to make my answer clear.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To permanently disable the display of files in unity dash, there are a few possibilities:

1. Using dconf-editor, edit the key com-unity-scopes. Remove 'home.scope' and 'files.scope' from the list. That way, the launcher will open with the application list by default.
2. Remove unity-lens-files using your package manager or run the following in the command line: `sudo apt-get remove unity-lens-files`

If you change your mind, in case of 1) edit the key to add 'home.scope' and 'files.scope' back to the key (e.g. `'home.scope', 'applications.scope', 'files.scope'`). In case of 2), reinstall unity-lens-files.

Comment: Ok. How do I add it back in case I one day change my mind?

Comment: Although that was not the original question, I added the ways to revert the change to my answer.